# Migrate an intermediate CA to a new root

Tags: certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, crl

Using the Microsoft CA is there any way to cut over to a new certificate authority from an intermediate authority?

Both my systems are Microsoft CAs - I have a 2008 R2 Enterprise CA (intermediate) and an old 2003 CA (root). The 2003 box bit the dust and I don't have good backups. I still have a few months before the CRL expires; instead of having to cut over to a new intermediate authority is there a ready way to simply point this intermediate authority to a new offline CA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research it does appear that it is possible to do this by adding the new CA to active directory, performing a reenroll certificate holders command on all automatically enrolled templates and manually updating the web, etc templates.

Since my organization had a CA on a box with a sharepoint installation we went ahead and took this opportunity to split up those roles.

Shane's answer at [Adding new root/enterprise CA without disturbing existing one?](https://serverfault.com/questions/276342/adding-new-root-enterprise-ca-without-disturbing-existing-one) proved quite valuable for this process.

Answer (score 1):

MS have good docs in this area, e.g.: [Active Directory Certificate Services Migration Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126170%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I've already looked at those pages. Unless you can point me to a specific page of some use I don't think that will be much help.

Comment: The steps for an enterprise CA migration will be almost identical to swapping out your standalone root CA.  Create a virtualised test rig with a backup of a DC and your CA(s) restored.

Comment: that appears to make the assumption that the offline root is available. Did I miss something?